# Create custom dictionary from character vector

Tags: r, text-mining, quanteda

I am trying to look for specific words in corpus using dfm_lookup().

I am really struggling with the dictionaries needed for the dfm_loopup().

I created a character vector named "words" which contains all the words that should go into the dictionary.

dictionary needs a list, so I am creating a list from the character vector before I am using dictionary().

```
dict <- dictionary(list(words))
```

But then I get

```
Error in validate_dictionary(object) : 


 Dictionary elements must be named: digital digital-tv digitalis ...
```

What do I have to change in the list command to get the proper output for dictionary()?

Is there a simplier version to look for specific words in a dfm? Because it was really easy with the tm() package.

Comment: As documentation and error suggest you need to name elements of the lists: **dictionary(list(words = words))**  
That should help. If not try reading carefully https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quanteda/versions/1.4.1/topics/dfm_lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to name the items in a list in order to use dictionary with `quanteda`. Here is an example:

```
library(quanteda)

words = c("cat","dog","bird")

word.list = as.list(words)
names(word.list) = words

dictionary(word.list)
Dictionary object with 3 key entries.
- [cat]:
  - cat
- [dog]:
  - dog
- [bird]:
  - bird
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot!

Comment: @BanffBoss122: You're welcome, glad I was able to help :)

Comment: The input `x` in `dictionary(x)` needs to be a named list, as stated in `?dictionary`. So `dictionary(list(mykey = c("value1", "value2")))` etc.